# In which moment of UIViewController's life cycle should I initialize property?

Tags: swift, initialization, viewcontroller

I have two difference ways. First is to initialize during `viewDidLoad()`. Another way is to initialize a property, like `read-only` computed property in the `ViewController` init. Which way is better and why?

Comment: It is too generic to answer, do you have a scenario and could you show it in show some code ?

Comment: No, I'm talk about common situation.

Comment: IMHO If they are private properties I usually initialise them when I declare them. Then in `viewDidLoad` I have separate functions to setup them. For Example `button` is a `UIButton` that I initialise as `private let button = UIButton(type: .custom)`. Then `viewDidLoad` I invoke a function called `setupButton` which configures the button. If you use a readonly computed property it needs to be defined as `lazy` so that it doesn't repeat the setting up every time it is accessed. I personally don't like to overuse `lazy` unless necessary.

Comment: IMHO, too many computed properties also kind of seems a bit cluttered to my eyes. Anyway it is sufficient to configure the button in `viewDidLoad` and would not be accessed before that.